# Unable to get SAML Attribute to Role mapper working in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, saml

I am using keycloak 14.0.0 and trying to map the groups attribute present in the saml response to a role. But it doesn't seem to be working. My mappers for firstName and lastName do work however.
Here is the SAML response to keycloak:

```
<saml:Attribute Name="groups"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xsi:type="xs:string"
                                 >/j1-general-operator</saml:AttributeValue>
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                 xsi:type="xs:string"
                                 >/j2-general-operator</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
```

Here is my mapper:

[image]

Comment: Is there a "/" in front of the group name?

Comment: I think you need to write your own mapper for this. smiler issue is https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/map-groups-from-saml-idp-into-keycloak/12266

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru I have seen this working for others, there is something that I am missing here.

Comment: @csbrogi Thanks for pointing that out, idk how i missed it. Keycloak had a toogle in mapper that sets the complete path (that includes the /) instead of just the group name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slash was getting added before the group name because of a toggle option (for showing full path) in keycloak mappers. After changing that toggle, slash got removed and it started working.